# State and prove the parallelogram law?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is asking me to prove the parallelogram law. I literally have no idea how to do this, and any help would be appreciated.

[image: This is the problem]

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align*}
  |\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}|^{2}+|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}|^{2} &=
  (\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}) \cdot (\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})+
  (\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}) \cdot (\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}) \\
  &= \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}+2\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}+
     \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}-
    2\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} \\
  &= 2(\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}) \\
  &= 2(|\mathbf{u}|^{2}+|\mathbf{v}|^{2})
\end{align*}

Comment: All too easy ;-)) +1