# Establish the parallelogram law

Tags: functional-analysis

Using that $||f+g||^{2}=||f||^{2}+2Re(f,g)+{||g||}^{2}$ for any pair of elements in a Hilbert space, establish the parallelogram law.

I believe the proof is this:

[How do I prove the parallelogram law?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702684/how-do-i-prove-the-parallelogram-law)

And there is also a Wiki-proof likewise (same one it looks like). But, this equation seems a little different than the one in my question...

is it the same? Their equation reads differently and I can't see how they're equivalent.

But, I'm surely confused with the notation $2Re(f,g)$; does this mean $2$ times the "real part" of $(f,g)$? What is the real part of $(f,g)?$

Comment: $(f,g)$ is the inner product between $f$ and $g$, which is a complex number in general. Notice that $$||f-g||^2 = ||f||^2 + ||g||^2 - 2 \text{Re}(f,g)$$

Comment: ohhhh, yes thank you. Good to see they are the same. Of course it seems so clear now :p