# Let a, b be vectors. Show that $a \cdot b = \frac{1}{4} (|a+b|^2 − |a−b|^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Let $a, b$ be vectors. Show that $$a \cdot b  = \frac{1}{4} (|a+b|^2 − |a−b|^2)$$

I am trying to write this proof for vectors and I am unsure how to start.

I know the magnitude of a vector $U$ is the square root of the sum of the elements squared or $||U|| = \sqrt{U \cdot U}$

However, I do not know any mathematical rules for $|a−b|$ as compared to $|a+b|$ and the significance of these magnitudes squared. I am definitely missing something.

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Lets say that $a = (a_1,a_2)$ and $b = (b_1,b_2)$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $|a\pm b|^2 = (a_1\pm b_1)^2+(a_2\pm b_2)^2$ and then the question becomes rather the following: Whats the relation between $(a_1+b_1)^2$ and $(a_1-b_1)^2$ for $a_1,b_1 \in \mathbb{R}$? Especially, what is $(a_1+b_1)^2 - (a_1-b_1)^2$?

Comment: If you are more comfortable with the fact that $|a|^2 = a \cdot a$, you have $|a\pm b|^2 = (a\pm b) \cdot (a\pm b)$. Then if you know some arithmetic regarding the scalar product, what is $(a+ b) \cdot (a+ b) - (a-b) \cdot (a-b)$?

Comment: Did you know the distributive law of dot product, i.e. $(a+b)\cdot c=a\cdot c+b\cdot c$?

Comment: If you were to take $($a_1$+$b_1$)^2$ − $($a_1$−$b_1$)^2$ strictly as real numbers you would get 4$a_1$$b_1$ which makes sense. So it's just similar for vectors and the dot product and you end up with a⋅b = 1/4(4(a⋅b)) ?

Comment: You can get some ideas here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702684/how-do-i-prove-the-parallelogram-law

Comment: so I use that principle and arrive at the conclusion a⋅b = 1/4 (2($|a|^2$ + $|b|^2$)) or a⋅b = ($|a|^2$ + $|b|^2$) / 2. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$|\vec{a}+\vec{b}|^2=|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$$