# Prove that if $z,w\in\Bbb{C}$, then $|z+w|^2+|z-w|^2=2|z|^2+2|w|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that if $z, w\in \mathbb{C}$ then $|z+w|^2+|z-w|^2=2|z|^2+2|w|^2$.
I'm just taking this course for the first time any hint or process is welcomed, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [State and prove the parallelogram law?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702684/state-and-prove-the-parallelogram-law)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|z+w|^2=(z+w)\overline{(z+w)}=(z+w)(\bar z+\bar w)=z\bar z+z\bar w+w\bar z+w\bar w=|z|^2+z\bar w+w\bar z+|w|^2$ and similarly $|z-w|^2=|z|^2-z\bar w-w\bar z+|w|^2$.  Thus...

Comment: Thank you! easier than I thought haha

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$. Now you can expand both sides using this property.

---

Notes.

This is called the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces).

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it now!

Comment: just did, sorry im new in this site